# Test authenticated Cloud Endpoints methods offline

Tags: javascript, java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm going on a long flight tomorrow and I'd like to be able to keep testing my cloud endpoints REST API while offline. The problem is that the `User` object is integral to most of my methods, and I need an internet connection to create valid OAuth tokens to call them from the client side (JavaScript).

On the Dev server though, no matter what account you log in on, the user is always the same (with email example@example.com). But if you feed it bogus tokens, it throws an `OAuthRequestException`.

Is there any way I can generate valid test tokens offline for the dev server or a way to access the `User` object without providing tokens at all?

Here's an example of a method I'd like to test while offline:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "hylyts.get")
public Hylyt getHylyt(@Named("url") String url, @Named("id") long id, User user)
        throws OAuthRequestException, UnauthorizedException {
    return ofy().load().type(Hylyt.class).parent(util.getArticleKey(url, user)).id(id).now();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a little documented way to inject a custom `Authenticator` class in Cloud Endpoints. This allows you to change the way the User is detected.

Here's how it works :

```
@Api(name = "myapi", version = "v1", authenticators  = {MyDummyAuthenticator.class})
public class MyAPI {
  @ApiMethod(name = "hylyts.get")
  public Hylyt getHylyt(@Named("url") String url, @Named("id") long id, User user)
        throws OAuthRequestException, UnauthorizedException {
    return ofy().load().type(Hylyt.class).parent(util.getArticleKey(url, user)).id(id).now();
  }
}
```

And here's what your `Authenticator` implementation could look like :

```
public class MyDummyAuthenticator implements Authenticator {
    @Override
    public User authenticate(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        return new User("mytestuser@domain.com");
    }
}
```

You can of course make it more complicated. Since you have access to the `HttpServletRequest` you can get the user's email from a HTTP header or something like it.

Note that with an `Authenticator` you have access to the session **in the local server but not in production**. In production, `httpServletRequest.getSession()` will return `null`. THere's a trick to still fetch the session from the datastore, [which I explain here](https://david-codes.hatanian.com/2015/06/06/using-http-sessions-with-google-cloud-endpoints.html).

Then there's the question of how to keep both the normal authentication solution and your `DummyAuthenticator` implementation. I think you can chain authenticators, but I'm not sure how it works. In the worst case, you can just swap the `Authenticator` implementation during your flights.

Comment: This is just what I was hoping for. Thanks! Heading home to test it and accept then off to the airport for a productive flight.

Comment: The only potential downside to this approach is that you have to use the `com.google.api.server.spi.auth.common.User` class instead of `com.google.appengine.api.users.User`, which doesn't have an ID property. See [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12060&q=endpoints&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log). But on the upside, I now know how I'm going to handle non-Google accounts in the future.

Comment: Note that you can extend the `User` class and add whatever your want there.